# Ionic 2 - No provider for Push

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59 trying to implement push notifications with Firebase, I think I did everything right but now when I run my app I get an exception: **Error in :0:0 caused by: No provider for Push!**

Any ideia how can I solve it?

There is my app.component.ts and app.module.ts

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
{Only App Pages ...}

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    {Only App Pages ...}
],
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    {Only App Pages...}
],
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**App.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {AlertController, Nav, Platform} from "ionic-angular";
import {StatusBar} from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import {SplashScreen} from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
import {Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from "@ionic-native/push";
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, 
                   public statusBar: StatusBar, 
                   public splashScreen: SplashScreen, 
                   public push: Push,
                   public alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.initPushNotification();
    });
  }

  initPushNotification() {
    if (!this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      console.warn("Push notifications not initialized. Cordova is not available - Run in physical device");
      return;
    }
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: "883847118563"
      }
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);

      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                  title: 'device token',
                  subTitle: data.registrationId,
                  buttons: ['OK']
                });
                alert.present();

    });

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('message', data.message);
      //if user using app and push notification comes
      if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
        // if application open, show popup
        let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'New Notification',
          message: data.message,
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Ignore',
            role: 'cancel'
          }, {
            text: 'View',
            handler: () => {
              //TODO: Your logic here
            //  this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message});
            }
          }]
        });
        confirmAlert.present();
      } else {
        //if user NOT using app and push notification comes
        //TODO: Your logic on click of push notification directly
      //  this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {message: data.message})
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                  title: 'clicked on',
                  subTitle: "you clicked on the notification!",
                 buttons: ['OK']
                });
                alert.present();
        console.log("Push notification clicked");
      }
    });

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to set `Push` as provider in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    {Only App Pages ...}
],
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    {Only App Pages...}
],
providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Push,//here
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In ionic native v3.x, all the plugins are set as providers and used by injecting in constructor.

Comment: Thank you! it worked...
I have searched so much and never found what was wrong... Thank you again

Comment: Thanks but now showing Runtime error "Push is not defined"

Comment: @LAnantaPrasad though this is the solution for no provider error in general, the push plugin by Ionic is not usable any more since Ionic cloud service is discontinued. You will need to look for any other notification service

Comment: Ok @SurajRao Thanks..:)